# Unable to install WebLogic image docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, weblogic

I want to create an empty domain with an Admin Server:

```
nunyet@lw202050777:~/weblogic/backoffice$ sudo docker run -d -p 7002:7001 -p 9004:9002 -v $PWD:/u01/oracle/properties store/oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.4
Unable to find image 'store/oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.4' locally
12.2.1.4: Pulling from store/oracle/weblogic
822ace0353cb: Already exists 
19841f86e7b5: Pull complete 
b3c7d6d987c6: Pull complete 
cc5da308016d: Pull complete 
91c19f73b26d: Pull complete 
afca886f8980: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:7f0cb6f693cc15c18ae279c30df8dbdda8073598cc09caab8f5f67ce150823d8
Status: Downloaded newer image for store/oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.4
a739318959cbbb3e544dfd09ebaf7bd2c051fa0c4c30330b5c6f04d65f1425de
```

but I can't access the AdminServer Web Console at:

```
https://localhost:9004/console, 
https://localhost:9002/console,
https://localhost:7001/console,
https://localhost:7002/console
```

This site can’t be reached

Comment: You mapped port 9002 to 9004 locally.

Comment: I believe the Administration Console is exposed on port 7001 by default. So you'll need to use the other port you have exposed, 7002.

Comment: Maybe try without https ? Usually when set up WebLogic is not https by default.